# Stripe Terminal iOS SDK location Id Error

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, payment

connectReader failed: Error Domain=com.stripe-terminal Code=9020 "No such location: 'tml_*****'" UserInfo={com.stripe-terminal:StripeAPIDocUrl=Error codes  com.stripe-terminal:Message=No such location: 'tml_*****', com.stripe-terminal:HttpStatusCode=404, NSLocalizedDescription=No such location: 'tml_*****', com.stripe-terminal:StripeAPIRequestId=req_VCP5***, com.stripe-terminal:StripeAPIErrorType=invalid_request_error, com.stripe-terminal:StripeAPIErrorCode=resource_missing}

receiving this error when trying to connect M2 reader using **Terminal.shared.connectBluetoothReader(selectedReader, delegate: self, connectionConfig: connectionConfig)** method i do confirm that backend have stripe implementation still this issue is comes up

Comment: The error message mentions that there's no such location `"No such location: 'tml_'"`. You should check if the location you specified actually exists on the account you're making the request on. Stripe Support (https://support.stripe.com/contact) should be able to provide more targetted help since they should have the tools to identify which account you're making the request from, where the location was registered to, etc

Comment: @alex thanks i will try to get in touch with support team